# Subsequences of a non-absolutely convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose there is a non-absolutely convergent series $s=\sum a_k$, and we define

$$s_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k$$

Then we have that $(s_{2n})_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and $(s_{2n+1})_{n\in\Bbb N}$ are subsequences of $(s_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$. Then suppose we "partitioned" the sequence in subsequences $(s_{\ell n+m})_{n\in\Bbb N}$, where $\ell n+m$ are the elements of the cyclic ring $\Bbb Z_\ell$, i.e. $0\le m<\ell$.

If the limit of all these subsequences converge to the same limit, we can conclude that the series converges conditionally?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you partition the sequence $s_n$ into finitely many infinite subsequences $s_{1,n},s_{2,n},\dots,s_{l,n}$ and you ask if convergence of these subsequences to a common limit implies convergence of $s_n$. This is true and can be shown easily straight from the definition.

Comment: @Wojowu, yes, you understood correctly. But I dont see clearly how we can prove this.

Comment: Sure, in fact all you need for it to be conditionally convergent is for the $\ell=1,m=0$ case to have a limit. Then all other choice of $\ell,m$ will need to have that same limit.

Comment: @enthdegree but what if I cant use $\ell=1$, it is enough for some $\ell$? Or we need that this must be true for all $\ell$?

Comment: Yes, for some $\ell$ if you have that for each $m\in\{0,\dots,\ell-1\}$ that $(s_{\ell n + m})\to c$ as a sequence in $n$, then $s_n\to c$ too. This can be proven from the limit definition using $\max$ on the $N$s that arise from Wojowu's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: suppose $s_{\ell n+m}$ converges to $l$ for $m=0,\dots,\ell-1$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Take $\varepsilon>0$. Then for some $N_m\in\mathbb N$, if $n>N_m$, then $|s_{\ell n+m}-l|<\varepsilon$. To prove $s_n$ converges to $l$, you have to find some $N$ such that $|s_n-l|<\varepsilon$ for $n>N$. Do you see how to find such $N$?

Comment: @Masacroso Indeed, good catch.

Comment: I see, yes, it is not hard after all. But I dont know why this "lemma" is not stated in any book, because is very effective to handle non-absolutely convergent series and see if they converge or not.

Comment: The lemma hinted to in this answer applies to **any** sequence and, it follows, it is true in case you want to apply it to the sequence of partial sums of *any* series, not only conditionally convergent ones. Yet I really can't see how this is "very effective" when working on the field...It is because it is a rather particular, very restricted case, that it is not, probably, mentioned in most text books, though some mention it in exercises, examples and etc.

Answer (score 2):

One fact that has nothing to do with series is that if you have a sequence $(b_n)$ and you partition it into a finite disjoint union of subsequences (for example, $(b_{2n}), (b_{2n+1})$ or $(b_{3n}),(b_{3n+1}),(b_{3n+2})$) such that all the subsequences converge to the same limit $L$ then $b_n$ also converges to $L$. The proof is immediate from the definition of convergence.

In particular, this apply to the sequences of partial sums. However, when you are talking about series, you can say more. The operation of passing to a subsequence of the partial sums corresponds on the level of series to inserting parenthesis around some collection of elements and you can ask when does the convergence of the subsequence implies the convergence of the sequence.

For example, if $a_k \to 0$ and you know that $s_{3n}$ converges to $L$ then you can also say that $s_n$ will converge to $L$ without checking what happens to $s_{3n+1},s_{3n+2}$ (not very surprising, as $s_{3n+1} = s_{3n} + a_{3n+1}$ and $a_{3n+1} \to 0$ and similarly for $s_{3n+2}$). Or if your subsequence is obtained by inserting parenthesis around elements that always have the same sign then the convergence of the subsequence implies the convergence of the original sequence.

Comment: Very nice. +1${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Oh, yes... your last paragraph is very enlightener, thank you very much. Well, it is a bit redundant to say that $a_k\to 0$, in any other case the series diverges.

Comment: Yep. This observation is useful sometimes to determined the conditional convergence of series. For example, this can be used to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor}}{n}$ converges.

Comment: Im thinking now that we can define the parenthesis non-linearly, right? By example a subsequence defined as $(s_{f(n)})$ such that $f$ is an increasing function.

Comment: @Masacroso: Yeah, you can put parenthesis around elements that have the same sign (which corresponds to looking at $s_{n^2-1}$) and then verify that you get Leibniz series.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in fact you only need that both of $s_{2n}$ and $s_{2n+1}$ converge to a common limit $L$ to prove this:

Proof:

Let $\epsilon>0$, then $s_{2n}$ convergent to $L$ implies that $\exists N_E\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n>N_E$, $|s_{2n}-L|<\epsilon$. Similarly, $s_{2n+1}$ convergent to $L$ implies that $\exists N_O\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n>N_O$, $|s_{2n+1}-L|<\epsilon$. Now consider $s_k$ (the sequence of partial sums for $s$). Then let $N=\max(N_E,N_O)$, then we know that for $\forall k>N$, $|s_k-L|<\epsilon$ by the previously mentioned inequalities because every $s_k$ is either an element of the subsequence $s_{2n}$ or an element of the subsequence $s_{2n+1}$.

Comment: The same idea can be applied to the other moduli, all you need is that it works for one modulus, then it must work for all moduli.